# What kinds of big DB related projects are not suited to be done using NHIbernate?

Tags: .net, nhibernate, architecture

NHibernate is a great. However I think its use must be limited (can't be an answer on all questions) and in some cases another approach should be better. Definition of "better" in this case is also interesting.

So I am wondering when you will not choose NHibernate and prefer another (which exactly?) DB layer architecture?

EDIT: well of course I am asking about cases when we are talking about big relational db, its obvious it cant solve tasks for non relational/sql dbs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NHibernate's key purpose is as an Object-Relational Mapper -- it largely eliminates the impedance mismatch between an object oriented language and the relational database. So the simple answer is NHibernate is probably not appropriate when that impedance mismatch is not a big enough issue to justify an additional layers of abstraction, complexity and potential performance reduction.

Looking at this from both ends, it is probably not appropriate for applications where:

- the object/data model is simple and there is no signifcant cost arising from an object/relational mismatch
- coding close to the DB is important for performance, architectural or maintainability reasons
- the application has unidirectional data flow (i.e. it is primarily a data writer or a data reader)

Answer (score 1):

NHibernate only works with relational databases. If you went with a NoSQL solution (such as RavenDB/MongoDB/etc) on your back-end, you wouldn't be able to use NHibernate.

That said, I use NHibernate for every project where the above does not apply. Once you've gotten over that initial learning curve associated with it, there's really no reason not to use it, except, perhaps as @degorolls mentioned, in scenarios where your application is primarily a data writer. You gain too much from using NHibernate to consider not using it, even with simple applications where you have a UI directly on top of a data store.

Answer (score 0):

NHibernate is not best choice when you need to process huge amount of data, for example when you do synchronization or replication tasks. It will be very slow. In this case its better to use some Integration Services of SQL Server.

Also if you need to execute really complex queries, then query API can stand on your way. QueryOver is great, but when you don't need to do unions and complex sub queries. LINQ isn't mature enough yet to solve all the SQL related things.